# MySQL query through PHP fix

Tags: php, mysql, forms, sql-update

I'm making a page, where depending on the HTML form data gets inserted/updated/deleted into/from the database.

As far as for the `UPDATE` goes, I have no more ideas how to fix it. The thing is, that you can update anything you want (for example `nazwa_klubu` only, if let's say you've changed your old `nazwa_klubu` and want to keep the new name (nazwa klubu = club name) in the database you type the name that you want to change to into `Nazwa klubu` in the `Wprowadz zmiany` form, and then in the second `Nazwa klubu` you type the name you want to be changed.

- I believe it is a minor upgrade to make it all work, without having to put countless if cases, but it's my third day with PHP, so I'm confused.

**EDIT:** So basically, this function works properly, if all fields are filled. But I want it to work even if we fill some of fields - well, I hope you get my point. What's the point of UPDATE if you can't even use it correctly? Rhetorical Q.

And this is how it currently works:

`UPDATE Koncerty SET nazwa_klubu = 'NewClubName', WHERE nazwa_klubu = 'OldClubName' AND`

But obviously I want this to work like this:

`UPDATE Koncerty SET nazwa_klubu = 'NewClubName' WHERE nazwa_klubu = 'OldClubName'`

No matter how many input's I'll fill in this form. The first 5 inputs are responsible for `SET` side, and the second five are after `WHERE` clause.

**Here's the code of the function**

```
function update($table, $data)
{
$new_klub = 'nazwa_klubu = ' . '\'' . $data[data1] . '\',';
$new_adres = 'adres_klubu = ' . '\'' . $data[data2] . '\',';
$new_zespol = 'nazwa_zespolu = ' . '\'' . $data[data3] . '\',';
$new_ile = 'ilosc_czlonkow_zespolu = ' . '\'' . $data[data4] . '\',';
$new_wystep = 'data_wystepu = ' . '\'' . $data[data5] . '\',';
$klub = 'nazwa_klubu = ' . '\'' . $data[data6] . '\' AND';
$adres = 'adres_klubu = ' . '\'' . $data[data7] . '\' AND';
$zespol = 'nazwa_zespolu = ' . '\'' . $data[data8] . '\' AND';
$ile = 'ilosc_czlonkow_zespolu = ' . '\'' . $data[data9] . '\' AND';
$wystep = 'data_wystepu = ' . '\'' . $data[data10] . '\'';

if (empty($data[data1]) AND empty($data[data2]) AND
    empty($data[data3]) AND  empty($data[data4]) AND empty($data[data5])) {

    echo '<span class="error">Zabezpieczenie: Musisz wpisac jakie zmiany chcesz wprowadzic</span>';
    exit;
}

if (empty($data[data6]) AND empty($data[data7]) AND
    empty($data[data8]) AND  empty($data[data9]) AND empty($data[data10])) {

    echo '<span class="error">Zabezpieczenie: Musisz wpisac na czym chcesz dokonac zmian</span>';
    exit;
}

if (empty($data[data1])) {
    $new_klub = '';
}
if (empty($data[data2])) {
    $new_adres = '';
}
if (empty($data[data3])) {
    $new_zespol = '';
}
if (empty($data[data4])) {
    $new_ile = '';
}
if (empty($data[data5])) {
    $new_wystep = '';
}

if (empty($data[data6])) {
    $klub = '';
}
if (empty($data[data7])) {
    $adres = '';
}
if (empty($data[data8])) {
    $zespol = '';
}
if (empty($data[data9])) {
    $ile = '';
}
if (empty($data[data10])) {
    $wystep = '';
}

    $safe_updates = "SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0";

    $sql = "UPDATE $table SET 
    $new_klub
    $new_adres
    $new_zespol
    $new_ile
    $new_wystep
    WHERE 
    $klub
    $adres
    $zespol
    $ile
    $wystep
    ";

    echo $new_klub;

    mysql_query($safe_updates);
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if (!$result) {
        echo '<span class="error">' . mysql_error() . '</span><br>' . $sql . '';
    }
    else { 
        echo '<span class="success">Wprowadzono zmiany' . $sql . '</span><br>'; 
    }

}
```

Comment: what is after `AND`????

Comment: Well, nothing in the example, since input in other fields is empty, it's adding `,`s and `AND`s after every variable, to make it work with full query. Read the **edit** part in question.

By the way, it's all clear when you read the code.

Comment: I think you have an extra comma at the end of $new_wystep so it's complaining about the WHERE being right after it.

Comment: you can try setting a column = column before the WHERE maybe ID or something so that it's always right syntax.

Comment: @RonakBhatt, and be unable to form complex query? Sure not.

Comment: @nobodynoone- what exactly you are trying to say from your comment??

Comment: @RonakBhatt that you did not understand the question. If I remove it, it won't pass with any more complex than one field filled.

Comment: You can append it during creation of query ...

Comment: Post your answer then, please - let's stop being rude ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use stack overflow as somewhere ask questions like "Fix my code".

But, you could just put all your `$new_` variables into an array

```
$new = array(
    'klub' => 'nazwa_klubu = ' . '\'' . $data[data1] . '\',',
    'adres' => 'adres_klubu = ' . '\'' . $data[data2] . '\',',
);
```

And then you can implode your array

```
$sql = implode(', ', $new);
```

Then you wont get trailing commas. Then use the same logic with `AND` and you'll get your SQL looking okay.

Comment: Accepted. Working with some minor corrections like deleting first `,` in every value of element in array